# MantisBT Bugtracker

Tags: mantis

I have installed MantisBT on my system & created/reported issue, now I have installed the same
version mantisBT on other system.How to migrate database from my system to other system.And next question is how to manage connectivity in both system (it should show update on each system)?

Answer (score 0):

Regarding the first question

> How to migrate database from my system to other system

as the version of MantisBT in both systems is the same, follow these steps:

1. Dump the "old" `Database mysqldump -uUSER -p old_database > dumpfile`
2. Load the dump on the new system `mysql -uUSER -p new_db < dumpfile`
3. You may also copy the configuration file from the old to the new system.
4. Do not forget the attachments. Just copy them.

In case you have access to PHPMyAdmin this process is much easier.